# Can I place flags over y-axis HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hey I am using HighCharts as my main graph library. 
I would like to highlight(or flag) specific points on y-axis.
I know that I can have flags over x-axis, can I do it for the **y-axis too**?

I am attach an example of flags over x-axis, can I implement this for the y-axis the same way?

```js
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        var lastDate = data[data.length - 1][0],  // Get year of last data point
            days = 24 * 36e5; // Milliseconds in a day

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Exchange rate'
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data: data,
                id: 'dataseries',
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 4
                }
            }, {
                type: 'flags',
                name: 'Flags on series',
                data: [{
                    x: lastDate - 60 * days,
                    title: 'On series'
                }, {
                    x: lastDate - 30 * days,
                    title: 'On series'
                }],
                onSeries: 'dataseries',
                shape: 'squarepin'
            }, {
                type: 'flags',
                name: 'Flags on axis',
                data: [{
                    x: lastDate - 45 * days,
                    title: 'On axis'
                }, {
                    x: lastDate - 15 * days,
                    title: 'On axis'
                }],
                shape: 'squarepin'
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

Comment: Flags attach to a series, not an axis. Arrange your data series to the yAxis values you want to flag, and attach the flags to that series.

Comment: How about [plotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines) or [plotBand](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotBands) on yAxis?